how to dynamically register implementation of EntryProcessor to Hazelcast server side?
Using an implementation of EntryProcessor in client side, And I have to add the lib to server side. Is there any dynamic way to register it to server?

When you run an EntryProcessor on map entries from the client side, it is uploaded to all cluster members. These members execute the EntryProcessor locally, eliminating the need for network serialization. As a result, you generally don't need to perform any special configuration on the server side. If your question is about something else, please clarify.
